# Empty projects code editor window won't appear

Tags: visual-studio

I installed visual studio 2017 community, and went to create a new empty project. When I created this project I could not find the window to type my code in, and there was a code definition window, but I couldn't type in it.

Where do I find the editor window for the code?

Comment: You need to add a file first before you can edit it.

Comment: If you're a beginner user I don't recommend using an Empty project for C++ because there's a lot of legwork involved in getting your dependencies, headers (and precompiled headers), libraries and other things configured. I recommend starting with the Console project template instead as that includes a prewritten `main` function that you can build immediately.